# App Engine 1.7.5 does not create new local_db.bin datastore file

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I just updated to GAE SDK 1.75 from 1.6.1.  I deleted the local_db.bin so that a new one would be created by app engine.  My app gets deployed fine to the local dev app server.  However, when I send a request to the app that requires getting data from the datastore I get the following in the console:

INFO: The backing store, C:...\war\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local_db.bin, does not exist. It will be created.

The local_db.bin datastore never gets created and I get the following exception:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response has already been committed

When I revert back to 1.6.1 the local datastore file is created and everything seems to work again.

Does anyone have any insight on this issue?  -Thanks.

Comment: Does your info log entry get made when the first data write is made to the datastore? It does for me. Also, I get another log entry whenever stored data is actually persisted to local_db.bin. You might want to wait 1 minute after data persistence to see if the db file has been created.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to GAE 1.8.1 or above and upgrade Java to 1.7.X. Coming to the datastore, you have to run your project with Data nucleus V2 which gives you JDO 3.0